# Manually install the xap file download on the phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I tried to install some xap application that downloaded from Windows Phone store on Mobile.
I moved them to Downloads folder and tried to install them from Store Application but there was no Option called "install local app".

I came up on the PC and just moved some file in Downloads folder and then the "install local app" appeared in Store Application.

Why do i can't install xap application that downloaded by phone on Windows Phone?

is there any trick that i have to do to install app ?

Answer (score 2):

When I need to install .xap file to a phone I usually use a tool called Application Deployment. It's a part of Windows Phone SDK.

You just connect your phone to a computer, locate a xap file in the tool and let the tool do the rest.

You need to have your phone developer unlocked.

[Tutorial on Application Deployment](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24119.windows-phone-8-1-app-deployment-how-to-deploy-appx-file-with-application-development-tool.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the XAP to the ***SD card***.

If you put the XAP in the phone folder, it will not work.
[How do I install donloaded apps](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/How-to/wp8/apps/how-do-i-install-apps-from-an-sd-card)

Comment: What about device doesn't have SD card?

Comment: I know that without the SD card cannot install the application manually.

Comment: the problem is I have to download xap file on PC and move them to the phone. when download xap files on Phone and is moved to the Downloads folder by file manger can't install apps.

Comment: I know the only way to install the downloaded XAP:

1) download the XAP on your PC

2) move the XAP to phone SD card 

3) will install the application from the  via the option "Install local app"

Comment: Does it download from PC even on CD card phone?